# append function not working to textarea after text edited

Tags: javascript, jquery

Append Function is not appending when textarea text edit . i tried to pull in the current value, append, and put back. but could not working .

```
function getSerial() { 
  var getValue = $(serial).val() + ",\n"; 
  var showValue = "#showSerial";
  $(showValue).append(getValue);
}
```

if i use val() it replace with before submitted value . the value of text-area will be added with comma like AL-2, Al-3 every single submit .

Comment: Provide your html quick?

Comment: Here: `$(serial).val()` where is the `serial` variable coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `val()` instead of `append()`:  I've created a test fiddle, will this work for you?

```
function getSerial (){ 
    var showValue = $("#showSerial");
    var getValue   =  $(serial).val()+ ",\n"; 
    if(showValue.val()){
        $(showValue).val(showValue.val() + getValue);
    }else {
        $(showValue).val(getValue);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mc5rrkmu/1/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response .  if i use val() it replace with before submitted value . the value of  text-area  will be added with comma  like AL-2, Al-3 every single submit . Hope understood

Comment: yes exactly like it . really grateful for your  attempt . @ Richard

Comment: can you give me an example of same problem using javascript (without using jquery).

Answer (score 2):

In place of .append() use .val()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.append()` use `.val()` as shown :-

```
function getSerial (){ 
   var getValue = $(serial).val()+ ",\n"; //make sure serial variable is defined above this line
   var showValue = "#showSerial";
   $(showValue).val(getValue + $(showValue).text()); //instead of .append() use .val()
}
```

Comment: Its great . i just replace text() with val() . Now its working Perfectly.....Thanks a lot

Comment: @kks...`.val()` and `.text()` both will work in your scenario you can use any..happy to help you..don't forget to mark this as answer if it helped!!

Answer (score 1):

Your ID element is a textarea. You should use `.val()` instead of `.append()`

How this:

```
function getSerial() { 
  var getValue = $(serial).val() + ",\n"; 
  $("#showSerial").val(getValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getSerial (){ 
   var getValue = $(serial).val()+ ",\n";
   var showValue = "#showSerial";
   $(showValue).val(getValue);
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain how this is different, thereby making it a correct answer.

Comment: @ rfornal need to use `.val()` not  `append()`

Comment: I understand that, but others might not ... I'm just saying the answer will be accepted quicker with an explanation of why.